# JavaScript adding decimal numbers issue

Tags: javascript, numbers

So I am making a script that adds two numbers (decimal numbers) together, which I have encountered a problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/esqnC/

I made the script, it turns out pretty good:

```
0.1 + 0.5  //0.6
0.2 + 0.3  //0.5
```

But soon I see:

```
0.1 + 0.2  //0.30000000000000004
0.01 + 0.06  //0.06999999999999999
```

And it does not look right to me. I know it is a shortcoming of using float point with finite bits, but I can't find a way to fix that.

```
Math.ceil   //No
Math.floor  //No
.slice      //No
```

**UPDATE**

Is it possible to multiply the numbers by 1000 first, then add them then divide it by 1000?

Comment: This is not a bug, simply real values have a fixed precision, so doing computations on real values may result in some small errors.

Comment: `Math.round(0.1 + 0.2)` is 0.

Comment: @Gazler - I need how to fix it, not why it happens.

Comment: The way around this is to perform operations on integers instead. So, if you're working with money values, don't work in dollars, but cents. (At the end of the calculation, just divide by 100 to get the value in dollars).

Comment: @Gazler Congrats :). Of course you will apply some math to decide the precision you need. On the other hand, everybody understands the issue that creates the situation in the question, but one thing is unclear to me: *what is the expected output?*

Comment: @bažmegakapa 0.3 and 0.07, I assume.

Comment: @Derek The solutions in the duplicate contain workarounds for your issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/588053/219743 for example.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Use `toFixed` to convert it to a string with some decimal places shaved off, and then convert it back to a number.

```
+(0.1 + 0.2).toFixed(12) // 0.3
```

It looks like IE's `toFixed` has some weird behavior, so if you need to support IE something like this might be better:

```
Math.round((0.1 + 0.2) * 1e12) / 1e12
```

Comment: nice, works: http://jsfiddle.net/esqnC/5/

Comment: @Derek after reading through some of the comments on the question linked as a duplicate, it looks like IE's toFixed might truncate instead of round. It might be safer to do something like this: `Math.round((0.1 + 0.2) * 1e12) / 1e12`

Comment: @GGG `Math.round()` is a great idea :)

Comment: @GGG - Looks like it is the ultimate workaround. Thanks!

Comment: @GGG: I don't know about this `Math.round` thing. Try `Math.round(11200030006000.126 * 1e12) / 1e12`

Comment: @KooiInc toFixed has the same problem with that one. I think for big numbers like that you'd want a big numbers library.

Comment: @GGG: probably. You `toFixed` solution worked here anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/D7ULx/

Comment: I was working with maximum two decimal places and this worked. `parseInt((66.65*100+33.45*100))/100`

Answer (score 13):

This is common issue with floating points.

Use `toFixed` in combination with `parseFloat`.

Here is [example](http://jsfiddle.net/49HGP/5) in JavaScript:

```
function roundNumber(number, decimals) {
    var newnumber = new Number(number+'').toFixed(parseInt(decimals));
    return parseFloat(newnumber); 
}

0.1 + 0.2;                    //=> 0.30000000000000004
roundNumber( 0.1 + 0.2, 12 ); //=> 0.3
```

Comment: Try it with 11200030006000.125 + 0.001

Comment: You are right, KooiInc and I updated it to 12 digits precision.
Still GGG's solution with Math.round((0.1 + 0.2) * 1e12) / 1e12 is elegant one!

Comment: But now the result is: `11200030006000.125 + 0.001 = 11200030006000.127`. It should be 11200030006000.126 ...

Comment: It is strange indeed. I also tried GGG's solution (http://jsfiddle.net/49HGP/6/) and it evaluates to 11200030006000.127 too. Do you have any ideas why this happens?

Comment: With numbers that big, I think it's just a problem with precision, not repeating decimals in binary. `10000000000000.126 == 10000000000000.127 // true`

Comment: why does this need to be so complicated?

Answer (score 12):

```
function add(){
    var first=parseFloat($("#first").val());
    var second=parseFloat($("#second").val());
    $("#result").val(+(first+second).toFixed(2));
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/esqnC/6/)

Comment: parseFloat(11200030006000.126) still comes out with 11200030006000.127

Answer (score 7):

Testing this Javascript:

```
var arr = [1234563995.721, 12345691212.718, 1234568421.5891, 12345677093.49284];

var sum = 0;
for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    sum += arr[i];
}

alert( "fMath(sum) = " + Math.round( sum * 1e12 ) / 1e12 );
alert( "fFixed(sum) = " + sum.toFixed( 5 ) );
```

### Conclusion

Dont use `Math.round( (## + ## + ... + ##) * 1e12) / 1e12`

Instead, use `( ## + ## + ... + ##).toFixed(5) )`

In IE 9, `toFixed` works very well.

Comment: Please give example of results, or at least create a fiddle

Comment: What's your conclusion?

Comment: new Number((11200030006000.125 + 0.001).toFixed(5)) still = 11200030006000.127, but if you leave it as a string (11200030006000.125 + 0.001).toFixed(5) = (11200030006000.125 + 0.001).toFixed(5) so Number is rounding. It's still a weird issue and you have to really make assumptions about your decimal places. still looking for an accurate solution I don't have to worry about