# Javascript adding numbers with commas

Tags: javascript, html, equation

I have four HTML fields, I grab their values and add them, in an equation that looks like this:

```
Total = Number(value1) + Number(value2) + Number(value3) + Number(value4)
```

Now some of the values might be equal to `1,078.00`, I get `NaN` as a result. What should I do ?

Comment: Please check I think you are adding any string in expression.

Comment: this can help to some extent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473994/javascript-adding-decimal-numbers-issue

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Remove the commas, obviously:

```
parseFloat(value1.replace(/,/g,''))
```