# Javascript/Jquery Incorrect sum calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am trying to calculate sum of some textboxes using javascript but it gives me inaccurate results in some cases.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ASLY7/)

**Enter values :** 234.32 and  32.34

**Result:** 266.65999999999997

**Expected Result:** 266.66

**Code:**

```
<input type="text" class="unitrate" />
<input type="text" class="unitrate" />
<input type="text" id="txtsum" />    


$(document).on('keyup', ".unitrate", function (e) {
            calculateunitrateSum();
        });


function calculateunitrateSum() {
            var unitratesum = 0;
            $(".unitrate").each(function () {
                //add only if the value is number
                if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                    unitratesum += parseFloat(this.value);
                }
                else {
                    $(this).val('0')
                }
            });
            $('#txtsum').val(unitratesum);
        }
```

Comment: http://blog.wambatech.com/javascript-gotchas-pt-1/ `:)` and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473994/javascript-adding-decimal-numbers-issue p.s.s I am not a downvoter, infact +1 from my end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [toFixed(2)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to round it to desired number of digits.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ASLY7/2/)**

```
 $('#txtsum').val(unitratesum.toFixed(2));
```

> The toFixed() method formats a number using fixed-point notation.

Answer (score 0):

You can round off number using:

```
Math.round(unitratesum * 100) / 100
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/raGnW/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toFixed(2)` to round off values.

use

```
$('#txtsum').val(unitratesum.toFixed(2));
```

instead of

```
$('#txtsum').val(unitratesum);
```