# jQuery adding numbers not correctly sum with decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a js file which calculate all totals when a user click, this will sum up all clicked rows but if the number contains decimal, would not add correctly, instead always put 00 on decimals

```
function calculateRevenue(){
        var sum = 0;
        $("input#check_count_revenue[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
            sum += parseInt($(this).attr("data-revenuecount"));
        });

        $("#revenue_count_totals").html(sum.toFixed(2)).digits();
    };
```

Then calling the function like this

```
table.on("change","input#check_count_revenue", function() {
        $(this).closest("td").addClass("checked_revenue");
        calculateRevenue();
        if ($(this).prop("checked") === false)   
        $(this).closest("td").removeClass("checked_revenue");
    });
```

If the row contains the following

```
 12.00
 13.00
```

That would correctly sum  25.00

But

```
 12.00
 13.01
```

Still got 25.00 instead of 25.01

Any ideas? I already tried parseFloat in place of parseInt, does not resolve

Comment: Well obviously `parseInt()` isn't going to work, because it discards decimal places *on purpose*... Once you fix that, you might want to read about floating point maths [in general](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) and  [in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473994/javascript-adding-decimal-numbers-issue?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I edited my Question @PHPglue

Comment: What is the `digits()` function that you use there?

Comment: You do know that `.toFixed()` will round to the decimal place, right?

Comment: It could be the JavaScript floating point issue, if the rounding is not the problem. To overcome this try multiplying every number by 10 before your mathematical operations then divide by the multiples of 10 to get the number you desire.

Comment: @Dekel digits() function just add comma every three decimal places, removing it wil not resolve the issue

Comment: Did you try to remove **both** the `digits()` **and** the `parseInt()` from your code?

Comment: Similar to @Dekel's comment, remove `digits()` and replace `parseInt()` with `parseFloat()`

Comment: The math works in FIreFox, but without, `.toFixed()` I get `25.009999999999998`.

Comment: You say that removing `digits()` won't resolve the issue. If it contains `parseInt()` then removing it will likely give the correct answer.  Have you tested without it (also changing `parseInt()` to `parseFloat()` in the above code)?

Answer (score -1):

This is a common problem not only in JavaScript but several programming languages dealing with floating-point arithmetic.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript) from StackOverflow, this [explanation](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch2.md#small-decimal-values) about how they work in JS, and this [CS docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for more information about it.

I think is **important** you understand the problem before giving you any "solution", but if you really need a serious and dependable tool to work with floating point values I recommend you to use [math.js](http://mathjs.org/).

Comment: I really don't think it's related. Run `(parseFloat('12.01')+parseFloat('13.00')).toFixed(2)` in your console, you will get 25.01. This it not the issue here...

Comment: It is the issue, you are just dealing with it using `parseFloat`

Comment: The question is regarding the usage of parseFloat... check again.

Comment: I get what you are saying and you are right, the way you are doing it is the way to deal with the floating-point arithmetic problem, but it doesn't make it go away.

Comment: This is because this is **not** the same problem.

Comment: Explain what is happening and why when `parseFloat(12.01) + parseFloat(13.00)` returns `25.009999999999998`. We all want to learn.

Comment: This is not your original question, and the answer to this specific question in the comment already exists in this answer (by dave gomez). But what you are saying is that in **your** code, when you do `parseFloat(12.01) + parseFloat(13.00)` you get `25.00`, and this **makes no sense**, so I guess something in your code is wrong, or you didn't post all of your code.

Comment: @DaveGomez the OP uses `.toFixed(2)` to address this problem

Comment: That's what I'm saying

Answer (score -1):

you can use toFixed() method

```
var num = 5.56789;
var n = num.toFixed(2);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

Answer (score -2):

See if this will work for you:

```
function sumFix(){
  var a = [].slice.call(arguments), d = a.pop(), s = 0, p = Math.pow(10, d);
  for(var i=0,l=a.length; i<l; i++){
    s += a[i]*p;
  }
  return (s/p).toFixed(d);
}
```

Then you could do:

```
function calculateRevenue(){
  var nums = [];
  $('input#check_count_revenue[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
    nums.push(parseFloat($(this).attr("data-revenuecount")));
  });
  $('#revenue_count_totals').html(sumFix.apply(null, nums.concat(2));
};
```

`sumFix` takes any number of arguments, the last one being the decimal places you need.

Normal usage without using `.apply()`:

```
console.log(sumFix(12.00, 13.01, 2));
```

Comment: Read the comments