# Need help for parseFloat Values addition

Tags: jquery

I have 2 divs

```
 <div id="cursoc"><p><?php echo $myresultf; ?></p></div>
```

Its value is updated onclick

```
<div id="balance"><p>0.0301</p></div>
```

This is main balance div
I am trying to update   `<div id="balance"></div>` by adding both divs in this way

```
var totalscore = $("#balance p").text();
var currentscore = $("#cursoc p").text();

 var bal = parseFloat(totalscore) + parseFloat(currentscore);
 $("#balance p").html(bal);
```

Ins start it adds correct but After few clicks instead of adding it puts value after the balance like 0.00301000008  instead of adding 0.00301 + 0.000008

Am I doing parseFloat wrong way, need to know what is causing this

Comment: add the click event as well. all related code to OP

Comment: added click function

Comment: @john your p tag incomplete in first tag, post your jsfiddle

Comment: any help if you can?

Answer (score 0):

> There is no any mistake in your code and it should work.
>   **It is really an issue, not your fault.**
>
> See:
>
> - [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)
> - [JavaScript adding decimal numbers issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473994/javascript-adding-decimal-numbers-issue)