# Why does the following code return 0.30000000000000004?

Tags: javascript, function

Why does the following code return 0.30000000000000004?

```
function nfunc(f1, f2) {
  return f1 + f2
}

console.log(nfunc(0.2, 0.1));

> 0.30000000000000004
```

Comment: A very similar question has been asked before here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Take a look at the below to resolve with decimal issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473994/javascript-adding-decimal-numbers-issue